# Cloud Firestore live Data changing like Realtime database

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on a project which was using `FRDB` (firebase real-time database) till now. But now i want to switch to cloud 'Firestore' so i converted the user storage to `Firestore` and disable the `FRDB`. But now in this situation i got stuck. i read some doc's from the `Firebase` but still confused as a newbie.

```
private fun checkFollowingStatus(uid: String, followButton: Button)
    {
    val followingRef = firebaseUser?.uid.let { it1 ->
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
                .child("Follow").child(it1.toString())
                .child("Following")
    }
    followingRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener
    {
        override fun onDataChange(datasnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            if (datasnapshot.child(uid).exists()) {
                followButton.text = "Following"
            }
            else{
                followButton.text = "Follow"
            }
        }
        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
        }
    })
}
```

This was working very well in `FRDB` but during the conversion of database i tried the below code but get stuck here.

```
private fun checkFollowingStatus(uid: String, followButton: Button)
    {
        val followingRef = firebaseUser?.uid.let { it1 ->
            FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
                    .collection("Follow").document(it1.toString())
                    .collection("Following")
        }
        followingRef.addSnapshotListener(object : EventListener<QuerySnapshot>{
            override fun onEvent(p0: QuerySnapshot?, p1: FirebaseFirestoreException?) {
                if (datasnapshot.child(uid).exists()) { //error: unresolved reference datasnapshot
                    followButton.text = "Following"
                }
                else{
                    followButton.text = "Follow"
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

I just want that when a user click on follow button the user's uid get stored in the following collection  himself and according to this text of the button get changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to check if a document exists in a subcollection.

Your existing code loads the entire subcollection and tries to check for one document client-side, which is wasteful even if you make it work.

You can instead just try to load that one single document, and check if you get a result.

```
val followingRef = firebaseUser?.uid.let { it1 ->
    FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
            .collection("Follow").document(it1.toString())
            .collection("Following").document(uid)
}
followingRef.addSnapshotListener{ snapshot, e
        if (e != null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Listen failed.", e)
            return@addSnapshotListener
        }
        if (snapshot != null && snapshot.exists()) { 
            followButton.text = "Following"
        }
        else{
            followButton.text = "Follow"
        }
    }
})
```

A few additional things to note here:

- The change I made is mostly a copy from the documentation on [getting realtime updates from Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#kotlinktx). So if there's an error, be sure to check that link for more info and samples.
- Your original code for the Realtime Database also didn't need to load the entire `Following` node to check for the existence of a single child node. I highly recommend checking all of your code for this pattern, as downloading more data than needed wastes both your and your user's bandwidth.